# ColdFusion 2016 and stored proc throwing invalid character error

Tags: db2, coldfusion-2016

I am trying existing code in a CF 2016 install... I get this error

"[Macromedia][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]ILLEGAL SYMBOL =; VALID SYMBOLS ARE ..."

the line identified is a param of a stored proc call that looks like this:

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn#" procedure="LIVE.STOPS">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT" dbvarname="STOPID" value="#val( variables.procstopid )#" null="no">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="TRIPID" value="#val( url.tripId )#" null="no">
</cfstoredproc>
```

I cannot find any mention on line of a change in stored proc tag - maybe the DB2 driver? I'm looking for any input. Thanks.

Other info;
Windows10, Apache2.4, connectiong to DB2 v10.

@pendo, Here is the stored proc - it should be noted that I abbreviated some of the sql, but the SP works and has for a long time in the app running CF10.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIVE.STOP(
    IN stopId BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    IN tripId INTEGER DEFAULT 0
) LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN

DECLARE updateTripId INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE minStopId BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE maxStopId BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE TripSearch_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT s1.fkTripsId
    FROM live.paymentsTripsStops s1
    JOIN  live.Trips t ON s1.fkTripsId = t.Id
    WHERE s1.fkStopsId = stopId 
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

DECLARE minMaxStop_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
       COALESCE(
           (
                SELECT s.Id
                FROM  live.Stops s
                JOIN  live.Trips t ON s.fkTripsId = t.Id
                ORDER BY s.Sequence
                FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
           ),
           0
       ) AS firstStopId,
       COALESCE(
           (
               SELECT s.Id
                FROM  live.Stops s
                JOIN  live.Trips t ON s.fkTripsId = t.Id
                ORDER BY s.Sequence DESC
                FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
           ),
           0
       ) AS lastStopId
    FROM   live.Trips t
    WHERE  t.Id = updateTripId 
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

IF TripId > 0 
THEN SET updateTripId = TripId;
ELSE OPEN TripSearch_cursor;
    FETCH FROM TripSearch_cursor INTO updateTripId;
CLOSE TripSearch_cursor;
END IF;

IF updateTripId > 0 
THEN OPEN minMaxStop_cursor;
    FETCH FROM minMaxStop_cursor INTO minStopId, maxStopId;
CLOSE minMaxStop_cursor;

UPDATE live.Trips
SET fkFirstStopId = minStopId,
    fkLastStopId = maxStopId
WHERE  intId = updateTripId;
END IF;

END
```

Comment: Can you post the stored proc code please?

Comment: Removing the dbvarname="" attribute - reverting back to the re-introduction of this attribute - and relying on ordinal argument positioning fixes the error, But that's a pain. I suspect DB2 not requiring a prefix like '@' in MSSQL or ':' in Oracle, is the issue, but I've got no way to confirm. Also - Calling the Stored proc via cfquery also works, no errors. Its a shame, as we just added dbvarname= back to the SPs a couple months ago

Comment: (Not familiar with DB2) Does it support any kind logging to see the sql statements generated? That might provide some clues.